# Negation of Filter not working as expected in R

Tags: r, filter, negation

[Data set]

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4.98 | NA | NA |
| 5.28 | NA | 3.21 |
| 5.12 | 5.14 | 3.16 |
| 5.09 | 5.12 | 3.18 |
| 0 | 0 | 7.12 |
| 0 | 0 | NA |

```
d %>% filter(x==0 | y==0 | z==0 | is.na(x) | is.na(y) | is.na(z))
```

Above R code give me correct results where it filers the dataset and display everything with either 0 or NA in any of the x, y or z as below

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4.98 | NA | NA |
| 5.28 | NA | 3.21 |
| 0 | 0 | 7.12 |
| 0 | 0 | NA |

But when I reverse the condition to negations it is showing everything.

```
d %>% filter(x!=0 | y!=0 | z!=0 | !is.na(x) | !is.na(y) | !is.na(z))
```

The expected result is

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5.12 | 5.14 | 3.16 |
| 5.09 | 5.12 | 3.18 |

But I received the entire data set

***Could you please let me know what mistake I made ?***

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a logic issue rather than an R issue here. If you replace your `or` statements with `and` then I think you will obtain the intended result and the negation of your original statement. In other words, `d %>% filter(x!=0 & y!=0 & z!=0 & !is.na(x) & !is.na(y) & !is.na(z))`.

Answer (score 0):

To reverse the condition you can add `!` to your original condition.

```
library(dplyr)

d %>% filter(!(x==0 | y==0 | z==0 | is.na(x) | is.na(y) | is.na(z)))

#     x    y    z
#1 5.12 5.14 3.16
#2 5.09 5.12 3.18
```

**data**

```
d <- structure(list(x = c(4.98, 5.28, 5.12, 5.09, 0, 0), y = c(NA, 
NA, 5.14, 5.12, 0, 0), z = c(NA, 3.21, 3.16, 3.18, 7.12, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```